# How to display info text in iphone application settings?

Tags: objective-c, plist

I wonder if it is possible to have a button in application settings just like the facebook app has:

[image]

As you see there is an `Info` entry. I know I can achieve this with the multi value specifier but it requires some values and not just text:

[image]

So when you tap on Info it opens a view that has just a long title element.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's look to below images:

[image]

This is a Root.plist in Setting.bundle. Here are Item5 - Group called 'Title' and Item6 - button called 'Hello'. Notice to the record `Filename` and value NewInfo.

---

[image]

NewInfo is a new `.plist` file which you should place into Settings.bundle. In Xcode right mouse click on Setting.bundle->Show In Finder->right mouse click on Setting.bundle->Show Package Content->Copy/Past for create new item(rename after, remove all unnecessary rows).

---

[image]

It is a content for NewInfo.plist

Answer (score 0):

Add new item to Root.plist in Settings.bundle. Then set type to Group and write your text in
the Title field.

Comment: The question is how to do it with the button, that you first have a button in settings which opens the text